# Identity of $(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $$ (a^2+2c^2)(a+c)(a+b)+ (b^2+2a^2)(b+c)(a+b)+ (c^2+2b^2)(b+c)(a+c)=(a^2+b^2+c^2)((a+b)(b+c)+(c+a)(a+b)+(c+a)(a+b))$$

My approach: divide by $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$ throughout.
Let the new expression be £.
Let $$x(1/(b+c)+1/(c+a)+1/(a+b)) + £ =0$$
Now put$$ x = -(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
We get 0  in LHS hence proved.
But since I use the result to be proved in my solution, 
I am looking for a different solution.
  2nd approach: from the first term ,$$a^4+2c^2a^2+(a^2+2c^2)(ab+bc+ca)$$,similarly for other two terms,
Factoring , $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2+(ab+bc+ca)3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
Or,$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2+3(ab+bc+ca))$$, further?

Comment: If you have no better ideas, why don't you just execute all operations i.e. get rid of all brackets? It just requires some work, nothing more. Then the identity will become obvious.

Comment: @peter.petrov I have edited my question to the step where I got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\quad LHS-RHS\\=\left(a^2+2c^2\right)\left(a+c\right)\left(a+b\right)+ \left(b^2+2a^2\right)\left(b+c\right)\left(a+b\right)+ \left(c^2+2b^2\right)\left(b+c\right)\left(a+c\right) -\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\left[\left(a+b\right)\left(b+c\right)+\left(c+a\right)\left(a+b\right)+\left(c+a\right)\left(a+b\right)\right]\\=\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)\left(c^2-b^2\right)+\left(b+a\right)\left(b+c\right)\left(a^2-c^2\right)+\left(c+a\right)\left(c+b\right)\left(b^2-a^2\right)\\=\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)\left(b+c\right)\left(c-b\right)+\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)\left(b+c\right)\left(a-c\right)+\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)\left(b+c\right)\left(b-a\right)\\=\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)\left(b+c\right)\left(c-b+a-c+b-a\right)\\=0\\ \therefore LHS\equiv RHS$

Answer (score 2):

A slightly less involved solution. Dividing both sides with $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$ means we have to solve
$$\frac{a^{2}+2c^{2}}{b+c}+\frac{b^{2}+2a^{2}}{a+c}+\frac{c^{2}+2b^{2}}{a+b}=\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{b+c}+\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{b+c}+\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{b+c}$$
Subtracting the right hand side gives:
$$\frac{c^{2}-b^{2}}{b+c}+\frac{a^{2}-c^{2}}{a+c}+\frac{b^{2}-a^{2}}{a+b}=c-b+a-c+b-a=0.$$